# How to calculate determinant in PCA?

Tags: matlab, pca, eigenvalue, determinants

Im going to program PCA, but for that, I have to calculate the Eigen Vector and Eigen Value.

My question is in calculate the eigen value we have to calculate the determinant of the matrix which all the (diagonal value - lamda).

In this case we can consider the number of lamda Depends on the matrix dimension.

I can program it manually for the matriks before the diagonal substracted by lamda.

But for the diagonal after substracted by lamda, how to calculate it??

Because, eventually we have to do factorisation to get the lamda (x1,x2,..,xn).

Here is the example :

```
      Matriks =[ 3 5 6
                 5 7 4
                 3 8 9]
```

Then we have to substract the diagonal value with eigen value, in this case because we havent knoen it, we will consider it as x.

```
       Matrix_New=[ 3-x 5    6
                    5   7-x  4
                    3   8    9-x]
```

And the determinant is (3-x)*(7-x)*(9-x).

I already tried to multiply it, but matlab gives error. 
Do u know how to do calculation (3-x)*(7-x)*(9-x) ??

I know there is matlab function, but Im not allowed to use it!!

I really appriciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the symbolic toolbox, if you have.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linalg-det.html

Then you have to find the roots of the polynomial.

If you dont have the symbolic toolbox, I think you have to make your program by yourself. One option is to use the minor expansion.

PS: By the way, the value of your determinant is NOT correctly evaluated.

Comment: question says "I know there is matlab function, but Im not allowed to use it!!" [sic]

Comment: I got this example :A = sym('[w 1; 2 w]');
solve(det(A),'w')...
But when Im trying to do it with  B= sym('[e 1; 2 r]'); solve(det(B),'e','r') it gives me error. 'e' represent the first diagonal value-x and 'r' represent the second diagonal value-x

Comment: @user3303896 unfortunatelly I am not able to test this for you. I dont have Sym matlab here and I used this toolbox a long time ago (maybe a version with different commands). Sorry about that

Comment: But do you know how we can posibble to perform " (3-x) " in Matlab,, which x is not known??

Comment: Look up the Leverrier-Faddeev algorithm, it computes the characteristic polynomial with matrix multiplications and trace operations. -- Unrelated note: You may eventually find that it is better to compute the SVD of the original matrix X that is used to compute the correlation matrix A=X'*X.